# How can I select the one of row from table view in iOS?

Tags: ios, json, uitableview

I have local JSON and have display on the first page.

After that I want to select one of the row from tableview. When I select the row, it will be display the other JSON from url, different rows have different json. However, I don't know how to find out the one of row. I try many ways but it can't work.

Here is the code of the first page:

```
@implementation HKTableViewController{
    NSArray *_location_array,*_hki;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    JSONLoader *location_jsonLoader = [[JSONLoader alloc] init];
     NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"locations" withExtension:@"json"];

    //NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://127.0.0.1/funhiking/index.php/index/getHKIsland"];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        _location_array = [location_jsonLoader locationsFromJSONFile:url];

        [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    DistrictTableViewController *district = segue.destinationViewController;

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];

    district.location = [_location_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        // Create a new JSONLoader with a local file URL
        JSONLoader *jsonLoader = [[JSONLoader alloc] init];

        //go to web to take json file
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://127.0.0.1/funhiking/index.php/index/getHKIsland"];

        // Load the data on a background queue...
        // As we are using a local file it's not really necessary, but if we were connecting to an online URL then we'd need it
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            _hki = [jsonLoader hkiFromJSONFile:url];
            // Now that we have the data, reload the table data on the main UI thread
            [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
              });
    }
}

#pragma mark - Table View Controller Methods

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"HKCell"];

    Locations *location = [_location_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = location.title;
    NSLog(@"%@", location.title);

    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [_location_array count];
}
```

Comment: use didselectrowatindex method of tableview delegate

Answer (score 0):

You can use didselectrowatindex delegate method of table view after setting delegate of table view, then you can get object from your array in this method and and can simply show the JSON url.
Happy coding...